# How to install pysvn on Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.0?

Tags: installation, redhat, pysvn

I tried to install pysvn on my server today, but met some problems as below:

```
[root@coffish pysvn-1.7.6]# python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pysvn.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pysvn.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pysvn.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pysvn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pysvn.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Info: Configure for python 2.6.5 in exec_prefix /usr
Info: Found  PyCXX include in /usr/local/src/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4
Info: Found  PyCXX include in /usr/local/src/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4
Info: Found   PyCXX Source in /usr/local/src/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/Src
('Error:', 'cannot find SVN include svn_client.h - use --svn-inc-dir')
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `egg'.  Stop.
error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: 'dist/pysvn-1.7.6-py2.6-linux-       i686.egg'
```

I also tried to find a svn_client.h file and placed it on current directory, but it didn't work. It is suggested that subversion client package be downloaded. But what is the subversion client package?

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

seems answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511202/pysvn-1-7-6-on-rhel6-error-not-a-url-existing-file-or-requirement-spec)

You did not mention python version, but that could be easily resolved if you have older python version. i have python 2.6.6 and the answer works for me.

The installation instructions are in INSTALL.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. and I find this solution and it is working.

Download the latest epel-release rpm from

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

for now :

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

Install epel-release rpm:

`rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm`

Install pysvn rpm package:

`yum install pysvn`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed subversion and subversion-devel packages?

```
subversion-devel.i686 : Development package for the Subversion libraries
subversion.i686 : A Modern Concurrent Version Control System
```

Bye