# pysvn-1.7.6 on rhel6,error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec:

Tags: python, review-board, pysvn

I have Python 2.7.3 installed on RHEL 6, and when I tried to install pysvn-1.7.6, I got an error. What should I do?

```
/search/python/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/CXX/Python2/Objects.hxx:2912: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
Compile: pysvn_svnenv.cpp into pysvn_svnenv.o
Compile: pysvn_profile.cpp into pysvn_profile.o
Compile: /search/python/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/Src/cxxsupport.cxx into cxxsupport.o
Compile: /search/python/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/Src/cxx_extensions.cxx into cxx_extensions.o
Compile: /search/python/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/Src/cxxextensions.c into cxxextensions.o
Compile: /search/python/pysvn-1.7.6/Import/pycxx-6.2.4/Src/IndirectPythonInterface.cxx into IndirectPythonInterface.o
Link pysvn/_pysvn_2_7.so
make: *** No rule to make target `egg'.  Stop.
error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: 'dist/pysvn-1.7.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg'
```

Comment: An aside, `pip install path/to/pysvn-x.y.z.tar.gz` completes, but does not install the package properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem, the reason is that i have made a mistake.
i just executed the following command, it is not in the instruction.

```
python setup.py install
```

the installation steps are (**the Source is the dir name in pysvn directory**):

```
cd Source
python setup.py configure
make
cd ../Tests
make
cd Source
mkdir [YOUR PYTHON LIBDIR]/site-packages/pysvn
cp pysvn/__init__.py [YOUR PYTHON LIBDIR]/site-packages/pysvn
cp pysvn/_pysvn*.so [YOUR PYTHON LIBDIR]/site-packages/pysvn
```

Comment: When I run `python setup.py install` if gives error `Cannot automatically detect your platform --platform` . What to do with this ?

Comment: @Javidan,execute the command `python setup.py install` do not install pysvn,following the instruction in the answer is the way to install it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip, it works for me. What is missing here to have `pip` reporting the package in the installed package list?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. and I find this solution and it is working.

Download the latest epel-release rpm from

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

for now :

`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm`

Install epel-release rpm:

`rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm`

Install pysvn rpm package:

`yum install pysvn`